# Tint color with UIView using colorWithPatternImage

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uiimage, uicolor

i need to use a pattern image that is repeated, but at the same time i need to tint it

When using

```
self.dividerView.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.dividerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"divider"]];
```

the tint color is not applied, what is understandable, but how to use the pattern functionality and also the tint color function? (e.g. have a tinted pattern image)

PS: the image is of course template image

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: nope, didn't found any solution for this yet